# Calculations in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So i have the following calculation:

```
test["calculation"] = 0.16667*10**((test["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But i want to add to this formula an if else

if the "Temp" >= 91.11 the formula has to be used. if the "Temp" is below 91.11 the outcome has to be 0.

This is the outcome i have with the formula at the moment:

```
    Temp    calculation
0   90.01   0.000164
1   91.03   0.000415
2   95.06   0.001315
3   100.07  0.002896
4   103.50  NaN
```

So for the 90.01 Temp. the calculation has be 0.

EDIT:
I want an ifelse to the formula. So when the "Temp" is <91.11 the calculation is 0. When the "Temp" >= 91.11 the outcome has to be the formula.

For example, this would be the outcome:

```
    Temp    calculation
0   90.01   0
1   91.03   0
2   95.06   0.001315
3   100.07  0.002896
4   103.50  NaN
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and also remove `reset_index`:

```
test["calculation"] = 0.16667*10**((test["Temp"].shift(-1)-121.1)/10)
print (test)
     Temp  calculation
0   90.01     0.000164
1   91.03     0.000415
2   95.06     0.001315
3  100.07     0.002896
4  103.50          NaN
```

EDIT: You can add mask by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
test["calculation"] = np.where(test["Temp"]<91.11, 
                               0, 
                               0.16667*10**((test["Temp"].shift(-1)-121.1)/10))
print (test)
     Temp  calculation
0   90.01     0.000000
1   91.03     0.000000
2   95.06     0.001315
3  100.07     0.002896
4  103.50          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of lambda function

```
test['calculation']=test['Temp'].apply(lambda x:(formula)if(condition) else 0)
```

syntax of lambda

```
lambda <arguments> : <Return Value if condition is True> if <condition> else <Return Value if condition is False>
```

for more ref [here](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-use-if-else-elif-in-lambda-functions/)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to extract exactly what you're asking from your question alone. But I feel like this should work:

```
test["calculation"] = np.where(test["Temp"] >= 91.11, 0.16667*10**((test["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10), 0)
```